# how to Create A SP with table variable and execute 3 SP statements in the same statement

Tags: sql-server

how to Create A SP with table variable and execute 3 SP  statements in the same statement .

exec [dbo].[sp_KPI_Churn_MTD_Current_Year]
exec [dbo].[sp_KPI_Churn_MTD_Previous_Year]
exec [dbo].[sp_KPI_Churn_MTD_Less_Than_Previous_Year]

Results should be as in the picture
Please see Image:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a table variable with a structure similar to the SELECT from the 3 procedures, insert into it and do the math:

```
CREATE PROC ... AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @data TABLE(Current_Churn_MTD int, Current_Goal_MTD int, Caption_MTD char(3));

    INSERT INTO @data
    EXEC [dbo].[sp_KTI_Churn_Current_Year];

    INSERT INTO @data
    EXEC [dbo].[sp_KTI_Churn_Previous_Year];

    INSERT INTO @data
    EXEC [dbo].[sp_KTI_Churn_Less_Than_Previous_Year];

    SELECT 'MTD' as Total
        , SUM(Current_Churn_MTD) as Current_Churn
        , SUM(Current_Goal_MTD) as Goal_Churn
    FROM @data
    ;
END
```

Output:

```
Total | Current_Churn | Goal_Churn
MTD   | 137           | 114
```

You could also change your Procedure to only return the 2 OUTPUT values:

```
ALTER PROC ... AS 
    Current_Churn_MTD int OUTPUT
    , @ Current_Goal_MTD OUTPUT
BEGIN 
...
END
```

And use this code instead in the new Procedure:

```
DECLARE @Previous_Churn_MTD int, @Previous_Goal_MTD int;
EXEC [dbo].[sp_KTI_Churn_Less_Than_Previous_Year] @Previous_Churn_MTD = @Previous_Churn_MTD OUTPUT, @Current_Goal_MTD = @Previous_Goal_MTD OUTPUT;

DECLARE @Current_Churn_MTD int, @Current_Goal_MTD int;
EXEC [dbo].[sp_KTI_Churn_Current_Year] @Current_Churn_MTD = @Current_Churn_MTD OUTPUT, @Current_Goal_MTD = @Current_Goal_MTD OUTPUT;

DECLARE @Left_Than_Previous_Churn_MTD int, @Less_Than_Previous_Goal_MTD int;
EXEC [dbo].[sp_KTI_Churn_Less_Than_Previous_Year] @Left_Than_Previous_Churn_MTD = @Left_Than_Previous_Churn_MTD OUTPUT, @Less_Than_Previous_Goal_MTD = @Less_Than_Previous_Goal_MTD OUTPUT;

SELECT @Previous_Churn_MTD + @Previous_Goal_MTD
    + @Current_Churn_MTD + @Current_Goal_MTD int
    + @Left_Than_Previous_Churn_MTD + @Less_Than_Previous_Goal_MTD;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Churn(
  Current_Churn INT NOT NULL,
  Goal_Churn INT NOT NULL,
  Caption NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #Churn
EXEC Churn_MTD_Current_Year
INSERT INTO #Churn
EXEC Churn_MTD_Previous_Year
INSERT INTO #Churn
EXEC Churn_MTD_Less_Than_Previous_Year

SELECT Caption
      ,SUM(Current_Churn) AS Current_Churn
      ,SUM(Goal_Churn) AS Goal_Churn
FROM #Churn
GROUP BY Caption

DROP TABLE #Churn
```

Comment: also can we do it as a store procedure and declare 8 variables better?1-Churn_MTD_Current_Year 2-Churn_MTD_Previous_Year 3-Churn_MTD_Less_Than_Previous_Year 4-MTD_Current_year_goal 5-MTD_Previous_Year_goal 6-MTD_Less_Than_Previous_Year_goal 7-Sum total Churn 8-Sum total goal ?????????????

Comment: You can use [OUTPUT parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to store results from the stored procedures into variables. The query I wrote gives you the sum for each column: 7 + 77 + 53 = 137; 13 + 72 + 29 = 114.

Comment: There you go: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/deea29/1.

Comment: when i execute it ,it gives me an error :((Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure sp_KPI_Churn_total, Line 0
Procedure or function 'sp_KPI_Churn_total' expects parameter '@Current_Churn', which was not supplied.